# Comprehension nested lists on dynamic list Python

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

Given the following list:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

My goal is to end up with the following:

```
b = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

My problem with this is, `a` does not have a fixed length ( if it did, I wouldn't need any help ). The length of the list is dynamic. Each loop pass adds a number to each sublist.

For example, `a` would look like this after the next loop pass:

```
a = [[1, 2, 3, 4], [4, 5, 6, 7], [7, 8, 9, 10]]
```

And `b` would look like this now:

```
b = [[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9], [4, 7, 10]]
```

I need the nth element from each sublist each time.

I tried list comprehension, searched this forum, but found no solution to my problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use `map` you can simply use list comprehension and the unpack operator `*`:

```py
>>> a = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> [[x, y, z] for x, y, z in zip(*a)]
[[1, 4, 7], [2, 5, 8], [3, 6, 9]]
```

But this is only guaranteed if your list `a` only contains lists as elements of same length.